# Ajax id = data-elementor-id

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, woocommerce, elementor

I can't get any further with my code. I have a code where the css id is queried.

```
_current = $('body.single-product .product.type-product[id]');
_current = (_current.length) ? parseInt(_current[0].id.match(/(\d+)/)[0], 10) : 0;
```

in my Elementor Shop there is not "id" but "data-elementor-id". Can you please help me to change the code?

I'm just on the line here and can't get any further.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a attribute selector for the `id` attribute so you just switch it to the data attribute.
Then you can use the data function to use its value.

```js
_current = $('body.single-product .product.type-product[data-elementor-id]');
_current = (_current.length) ? parseInt(_current.data().elementorId.match(/(\d+)/)[0], 10) : 0;
console.log(_current);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="single-product">
  <div class="product type-product" data-elementor-id="cid-23543654">A really nice car.</div>
</body>
```